# Classe MessageDigest e hash com MD5 em java

Tags: java, hash, md5

Estou testando a criação de Hash usando essa classe, e vi em vários sites, inclusive no [SOEn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/421696/5524514), o uso de trechos semelhante ao seguinte para criar hashs usando md5, porém sem muita explicação do funcionamento(em português, pelo menos):

```
    String s = "teste1234";
    MessageDigest m = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    m.update(s.getBytes("UTF-8"), 0, s.length());
    System.out.println("MD5: " + new BigInteger(1, m.digest()).toString(16));
```

Minha dúvida é, o que está acontecendo neste código até a criação do hash?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A classe [`MessageDigest`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/MessageDigest.html) provê funcionalidades de *hashing*.

O termo *digest* se refere a um tipo de "resumo" dos dados, ou seja, nada mais do que um *hash* faz, gerando uma sequência de bytes relativamente pequena independente do tamanho original dos dados.

A linha:

```
MessageDigest m = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
```

Recupera uma instância que usará o algoritmo `MD5` através do método *factory* `getInstance`. É análogo ao uso de outras APIs como `Calendar.getInstance()`, por exemplo, onde diferentes tipos de calendários podem ser retornados.

Os algoritmos que são suportados pelo Java em todas as plataformas são:

- `MD5`
- `SHA-1`
- `SHA-256`

Agora que temos o algoritmo definido, vamos à próxima linha:

```
m.update(s.getBytes("UTF-8"), 0, s.length());
```

Na verdade isso é o mesmo que:

```
m.update(s.getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

Aqui, o método [`update`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/MessageDigest.html#update-byte:A-) define a mensagem que será resumida, ou seja, o conteúdo onde o hash será aplicado.

Você pode chamar este método várias vezes para compor uma mensagem mais longa, de forma é possível processar conteúdos maiores que a memória disponível.

Agora que temos o algoritmo e o conteúdo a ser processado, vamos a um trecho da última linha:

```
m.digest()
```

O método [`digest`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/MessageDigest.html#digest--) finaliza o processamento e retorna, neste caso, o *hash* `MD5` da mensagem, retornando então ao estado inicial, pronto para receber um novo conteúdo e gerar um novo *hash*.

O retorno de `digest` é uma sequência de bytes representando um grande número. Então, a implementação acima usa um construtor de [`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger-int-byte:A-) para converter os bytes num número. Esse construtor recebe dois parâmetros:

1. *signum*: o sinal do número, isto é, se ele é positivo ou negativo. O valor `1` trata o número como positivo.
2. *magnitude*: o número em si. Quando falamos de bytes, é fácil esquecer que tudo em computação é representado numericamente em binário. O que essa rotina faz é extrair exatamente o valor representado pela sequência de bytes, ignorando qualquer formato de representação numérica, por isso é que o sinal tem que ser passado em outro parâmetro.

Logo na sequência, o método [`toString(radix)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#toString-int-) é chamado com o valor `16` e converte o número para um texto em formato hexadecimal (base 16).

Isso poderia ser reescrito de uma forma que, na minha opinião, fica mais evidente:

```
String message = "teste1234";
byte[] hash = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5").digest(message.getBytes("UTF-8"));
System.out.println("MD5: " + new BigInteger(1, hash).toString(16));
```

#### [Código funcional no IdeOne](https://ideone.com/Xz6vG6)

Comment: Só uma dúvida, no construtor do BigInteger, você está passando 2 argumentos, fui ver na documentação e fala que o primeiro é um *signum*. Não entendi muito bem pela documentação, pra que serve esse parametro?

Comment: Testei aqui, deu erro no vetor bytes[], tipo não conhecido e não tem sugestão de import. O método digest não aceita String como parametro também.

Comment: @DiegoF Acabei deixando alguns erros de digitação porque estava sem um ambiente para testar, mas agora está corrigido.

Comment: Também adicionei mais explicação sobre o argumento do construtor de `BigInteger`.

Comment: Interessante esse parâmetro do `toString()`, testei com outras bases e ele retorna valores bem diferentes de acordo com a base.