# Utilização da classe Big Integer na construção de um hash MD5

Tags: java, hash, md5, biginteger

Encontrei numa outra postagem aqui mesmo do SO o seguinte exemplo de código para geração de um hash por meio do MD5:

```
String message = "teste1234";
byte[] hash = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5").digest(message.getBytes("UTF-8"));
System.out.println("MD5: " + new BigInteger(1, hash).toString(16));
```

Entretanto, não entendi como é possível converter um número (representado pelo BigInteger) em um texto.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Classe MessageDigest e hash com MD5 em java](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/116349/classe-messagedigest-e-hash-com-md5-em-java)

Comment: Veja a resposta do [utluiz♦](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/227/utluiz), nela, ele explica exatamente tudo que está acontecendo nessa conversão.

Comment: Na verdade, a grande maioria das classes em java, possui o método `toString()`, é ele quem faz essa conversão. Cada classe tem sua implementação própria deste método.

Comment: @DiegoF tem alguma que não tem?

Comment: @bigown por isso respondi como comentário, não tenho certeza se todas tem kkkk

Answer (score 1):

Na verdade o método toString(16) irá converter para hexadecimal por isso do 16. como você pode ver hash é um byte array e se você for observar o construtor do BigInteger o parametro byte[] é representado como: Representação binária da magnitude do número. Você não precisa necessariamente utilizar a classe BigInteger para tal tarefa. Um exemplo prático para você entender melhor a lógica:

```
    String message = "teste1234";
    byte[] hash = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5").digest(message.getBytes("UTF-8"));

    char[] HEX_CHARS = "0123456789abcdef".toCharArray();
    char[] chars = new char[2 * buf.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < hash.length; ++i)
    {
    //Operadores bitwise para representar o valor do byte em hexadecimal
    chars[2 * i] = HEX_CHARS[(buf[i] & 0xF0) >>> 4];
    chars[2 * i + 1] = HEX_CHARS[buf[i] & 0x0F];
    }
    System.out.println("MD5: " + new String(chars));
```

No caso do valor ser convertido para "String" isso nada mais é do que os operadores de bitwise como mostrado acima.

Abraços